# In the most recent update of android studio, how do I import Modules?

Tags: android

I just updated and I am trying to import BaseGameUtils Library but under file there is no more import module option. Thanks for any and all help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > New > Import Module...

And, no, I don't know why they organized the menu that way.